# Web application latency spikes after moving from m4 to i3 instances

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, tomcat

I have a java web application running on Tomcat. It serves data off of embedded databases which are essentially files. It was hosted on AWS m4 instances and was migrated to AWS i3 instances.

I now see periodic(hourly) spikes in the 99.9 latency i.e. while responding to requests. What could be the reason? How to debug and mitigate this

The files are refreshed every 1 hour by a background job. The files are loaded in into memory from disk using Linux system commands. The spikes seem to overlap with this.

Comment: Are you using the ephemeral disk(s) on the i3?  If so, what OS and version are you running?  You will need drivers and proper configuration -- the [NVMe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NVM_Express) SSD ephemeral disks on the i3 instances are somewhat bleeding edge, and are unfortunately not plug and play.

Comment: yes, there are ephemeral nodes attached to this drive; I'm using redhat linux 4.4

Comment: You might keep an eye on the output of `iostat -x 1`. A spike to 100% in `%util` that is not accompanied by sensible spikes in the other values (and, if I remember right, `avgqu-sz` showing a nonsensical value of 1.0) would be giveaways that the NVMe support in RH4.4 isn't suited to these disks.   Officially, you need either Ubuntu 16.04 or "the latest" Amazon Linux. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ssd-instance-store.html#nvme-ssd-volumes ...that's not to say it won't work, but I'm unfamiliar with whether this hardware is supported in RH 4.4.

Comment: Honestly, this is a question more on-topic at sister site [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com), which is [*"a question and answer site for managing information technology systems in a business environment."*](https://serverfault.com/tour) (Stack Overflow is supposed to be about programming, though there is some overlap). You may wish to post it there, and delete this one, as cross-posting is discouraged.  Perhaps capture some observations with `iostat` and see what you can find about NVMe support in RH, first.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about "Server Fault" I'll move this question there